# dont want a random number to show twice

Tags: c#, shuffle

I am trying to save random numbers in a list, the same number can not come twice.
It´s a BINGO game where this method is used to display ex B12, then the user hits enter and a new number will show. This will keep on until the user writes q.

This works, BUT the number can show up twice...

```
static void bingo()
{
    Random rnd =new Random();
    List<int> check = new List<int>();
    string choice = "";

    while (choice != "Q")
    {
        int number = rnd.Next(1, 76);

        while (!check.Contains(number))
        { 
            kontroll.Add(number); 
        }
        if (number <=15)
        {
            choice = Interaction.InputBox("B" + number);
            choice = choice.ToUpper();
        }
        else if(number <= 30)

        etc.
```

Comment: so generate a list of all possible letters/numbers first and then shuffle that list and then iterate through the list. you'll never get a repeat as long as you keep moving "forward" in the list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Randomize a List<T> in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work (if I'm reading your question correctly)

Enumerable.Range(1,76).OrderBy(n => rnd.NextDouble())

Comment: this answer hints at a very good solution, but you hasn't followed it through all the way yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. Keep track of what numbers have been "called" - if a number is in the list, pick a different one
2. Remove numbers that have been called from the original list, then pick a new one at random each time.
3. Sort the list of possible values by a random number and just work though the list

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use a `HashSet`.

```
var usedNumbers = new HashSet<int>();
...
int number;
do {
    number = rnd.Next(1, 76);
} while (usedNumbers.Contains(number));
usedNumbers.Add(number);
```

Comment: -1: This is one of the worst implementation of shuffle since picking last numbers will take a bit less than forever (there will be 70+ items selected and random number would have to hit one of remaining 5- slots).

Comment: It depends how many numbers you will pick. If you are picking ten numbers out of 76. There will be no problem. (Letting pick the user all the numbers of the set would let him win all the time.)

Comment: According to the question "It´s a BINGO game" so there is a good chance that all numbers will need to be picked (or at least significant portion).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  It's still just O(72^2) which just about any computer can handle

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bingo_(U.S.)) "The most chips one can place on a Bingo board without having a Bingo is 19".

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes  Have you ever played bingo and have had a number called out that wasn't on your sheet?

Comment: I do not play bingo, but those who play do not always win. In fact they rarely win, which means that only a small part of the possible numbers is picked at each round.